# AngularJS version compatibility with Kendo UI

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

As per the Kendo Documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/prerequisites#supported-angularjs-versions) . A specific release of Kendo is associated with a Angular version.

My questions is:

1. Can I use any other angular version than supported version as my Application is hosted on a different version of angular? As of today Kendo is supporting angular 1.3 , Can I use it with my app running on angular 1.4 or 1.2.28?
2. What are the chances that components will work correctly with different version in place. I am aware that kendo uses their custom directives for all their components. And hopefully should not interfere with angular version.

I am evaluating the use of Kendo Angular for my application .

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing Kendo UI is guaranteed to work with AngularJS 1.3. There are known incompatibilities with 1.2.x although some people still use it today. Angular 1.4 support is not yet fully tested.

Answer (score 0):

I am using angularjs version 1.2.22 with kendo ui version of v2014.2.903 and everything works fine.